# How can i detect qr code scanning is done from a image and not from a print out?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief explanation:** I am able to scan `qr code` from my ionic application. But  i want to know if qr code is scanned from a image or from a print out. What is the best possible solution to achieve this ?

I want to stop the users who scan `qr codes` by taking their pictures. How can i do this ?

> Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: The only way I can think to do this is have different QR Codes, one indicating the image, and the other for print. Your website would then have to ensure the print version was used when printing or saving, and not the actual image you generated.

Comment: no the problem is my guards scan the qr codes which are placed at different places, i have a doubt they have taken pics of all in another device and they scan them while sitting in their ffice,  got my problem now ?

Comment: I see, they are not moving about getting the QR code, but rather scanning off one on a page instead of going to an external location.  What about adding the geolocation then to ensure they are where the QR code is, then it does not matter which one they scan, since they are at least at the location then need to be at?

Comment: geolocation does not work inside small properties , sadly its not at all accurate

Comment: Maybe something with the accelerometer, similar to counting steps, to see if you cover the ground?  Maybe bluetooth beacons that the application has to detect?  I am not sure what else might be doable.